# Intersection of two points in Ruby

Tags: ruby, math, line

I want to find intersection of two points in Ruby. What type of checks should be there so that the function works for all cases.

Pseudocode code is

intersection(range1, range2)

- notCommonR1 = part of range1 which is not common
- common = common part between both ranges
- notCommonR2 = part of range2 which is not common

For example

```
intersection([0, 3], [2, 4]) == {
:range1 => [[0, 2]],
:both => [2, 3],
:range2 => [[3, 4]]
}
```

Comment: for me it is not clear. `part of range1 which is not common` with which?

Comment: Like Range1 is a line from 1---4 and Range2 is a line 3---4 
1---3 is a part of range1 which is not a part of range2.

Comment: `:range1 => [[0, 2]]` and `:range2 => [[3, 4]]` how does it come?

Comment: what's the source input? on which this mathematics has to be done?

Comment: What do you mean by 'the intersection of two points'? Two points can't intersect - either they are the same point, or different points. Maybe you meant the intersection of two *lines*?

Comment: @ColonelPanic You are close, but I don't think the OP meant two lines. I think the OP meant two segments (or in other words, two closed sets of points).

Comment: @Sawa that makes sense. [Intervals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics))!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly straightforward; there aren't really any special checks to make here; the only special case is if there is no common part between the ranges.

```
def intersection(a, b)
  # Sort so that a1 < a2, b1 < b2, a1 < b1
  a, b = [a.sort, b.sort].sort
  a1, a2 = a
  b1, b2 = b

  if a2 > b2
    {range1: [[a1, b1], [b2, a2]], both: [[b1, b2]], range2: []}
  elsif a2 >= b1
    {range1: [[a1, b1]], both: [[b1, a2]], range2: [[a2, b2]]}
  else
    {range1: [[a1, a2]], both: [], range2: [[b1, b2]]}
  end
end
```

Depending on how you use both, `nil` as a value may not be ideal; use whatever indicates no common range.

Comment: What if there are same values among the four variables?

Comment: -1. When you do `intersection([0, 4], [2, 3])` with your code, it returns `{
  :range1 => [
    0,
    2
  ],
  :both   => [
    2,
    4
  ],
  :range2 => [
    4,
    3
  ]
}
`.

Comment: It seems I was somewhat hasty in saying there were no other special cases. My apologies, I've updated my code so that it should work. (I now also understand better why you wanted the ranges to be encapsulated in lists) If variables are the same it will use ranges such as [1, 1]. Of course this doesn't make sense if the ranges are considered exclusive, in which case a little extra code would be needed to filter it out.

Answer (score 1):

```
def intersection((x1, x2), (x3, x4))
  h = {}
  e1, e2 = x1..x2, x3..x4
  [x1, x2, x3, x4].sort.each_cons(2) do |x5, x6|
    key =
    case [e1, e2].select{|e| e.include?(x5..x6)}
    when [e1] then :range1
    when [e2] then :range2
    when [e1, e2] then :both
    end
    h[key] ||= []
    h[key].push([x5, x6])
  end
  h
end
```